# Magento 1.9 - memcached not working while using in shared environment

Tags: magento-1.9, memcached, caching

I am configuring multiple `Magento 1.9` instances on an `amazon server`. I want to store my sessions on `memcached`. for that I am using below configuration in my `local.xml` as suggested in magento.

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

But once I set this up, session seems stop working. I cannot login to admin, front end, Cart not working properly.

Can anyone tell if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: what you have running on port 11211?

Comment: memcached is running on port 11211